# Recursive version of the binary search that finds the left border in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Good day.
I am sitting the second day and can not understand how to write a recursive binary search.
The task is the following, find the index of the left border.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4RHC.jpg
Under various conditions, different modifications of the binary search are needed. There are four options:

- Find the last element less than the specified one (left border)
- Find the first element equal to the given one (the first entry)
- Find the last element equal to the given one (the last entry)
- Find the first element greater than the specified (right border)

The left and right borders can be thought of as positions in the array where the desired object should be inserted in order not to disturb the sorting. At the same time, the right border is the position of insertion at the end of a series of identical objects, and the left border is the position of insertion at the beginning of a series of identical objects.

For example, by searching for the right and left borders, you can calculate the number of elements in an array whose values lie in a given range [minValue, maxValue]:

```
count = BinSearchRightBorder(arr, maxValue, -1, arr.Length) - BinSearchLeftBorder(arr, minValue, -1, arr.Length) - 1;
```

Note that the task of finding the first occurrence is easy to reduce to the problem of finding the left border. And similarly, the last occurrence is reduced to the right border.

When searching for boundaries, it is reasonable to assume that the left boundary can take the value -1 if the zero element is already equal to the given one. And the right border can take the value of array.Length, if the last element is equal to the specified one. Naturally, then you need to start a binary search with left = -1 and right = array.Length.

In this task, I need to add a recursive version of the binary search that finds the left border, that is, the index of the maximum element of a lower value and if there is no required element in the table, return -1; The code must be recursive.

Again, the meaning of a binary search is a gradual shift of the boundaries, i.e. [0, 10] the interval for the array turns into [0, 5] then in [2, 5] then in [4,5] then element [4]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BinarySearchApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long[] arr = { -5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 100};
            FindLeftBorder(arr, 2);

        }

        private static int FindLeftBorder(long[] arr, long value)
        {
            return BinSearchLeftBorder(arr, value, -1, arr.Length);
        }

        public static int BinSearchLeftBorder(long[] array, long value, int left, int right)
        {
            if (left == right)
            {
                if (array[left] == value) return left;
                return -1;
            }

            var m = (left + right) / 2;
            if (array[m] < value)
                return BinSearchLeftBorder(array, value, m, right - 1);
            return BinSearchLeftBorder(array, value, left, m);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me write tests so that I could find the error in Visual Studio?
What is wrong in my code? Any comments are welcome!

I wrote the code, but I just can not figure out how to return -1?
I'm still a very amateurish beginner in C# so I apologize in advance for the stupidity of this question.
Thanks in advance to everyone for the answer!

Comment: the link to the image is updated

Comment: m is in both the right and the left branches.  Also the rightmost is getting lost every step along the right branch.  It should probably be `m , right `  and `left , m - 1`

Comment: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

Comment: One way to try to figure it out is to start with an array that is only 1 element long, and get it working with that.   Then move up to an array that is 2 elements long.  Once you get to 3 elements long, if you are doing it recursively, you will be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(left == right - 1) return left;
var m = (left + right) / 2;
if (array[m] < value)
   return BinSearchLeftBorder(array, value, m, right);
return BinSearchLeftBorder(array, value, left, m);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.